Group isomorphic to semidirect product quotient s.t. the exact sequence does not split
The problem that I have is to find an example for a group $G$ with normal subgroup $N$ s.t. $G\simeq N \rtimes G/N$ but the direct sequence $$1\to N\overset{\iota}{\to} G \overset{\pi}{\to}G/ N\to 1$$ does not split at $\pi$ i.e. there is no homomorphism $\varphi:G/N\to G$ s.t. $\pi \circ \varphi = \text{id}_{G/N}$. (To clarify $\iota: n\mapsto n$ is the natural embedding and $\pi: g\mapsto gN$ is the canonical projection.)
To give some context, the problem arose from a task which stated that the group is isomorphic iff. the sequence split. But after further discussion with the professor and other staff yielded the assumption that $G$ being isomorphic to a semidirect product does not necessarily imply that the sequence splits.
My question would be if someone could explain why this true or false and given that it is true, describe a way to construct an example.
So far I have considered abelian or finite groups, but in both cases constructing such an example did not seem to work.

It might be worth thinking about $G=S_3$, $N=A_3$.

@JMM given that there are only two cosets i.e. $A_3$ and $S_3-A_3$ the projection boils down to the sign of the permutation and you can easily define a right inverse i.e $\varphi(A_3)=id$ and $\varphi(S_3-A_3)=(1,2)$, still thanks for giving an example to try

I don't understand this question. The isomorphism shows there is a subgroup $H\le G$ isomorphic to $G/N$, and that subgroup maps isomorphically (via $\pi$) to $G/N$. The inverse of this isomorphism (composed with the inclusion of $H$ into $G$) gives the splitting, no?

Based on the answer below, I guess in the isomorphism to the semidirect product, you don't insist it is the identity on $N$, and that is where things fail.

The classic counterexample for abelian groups is $$0\to 2\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow\mathbb Z\times\bigoplus_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\overset{\pi}\twoheadrightarrow\bigoplus_{\mathbb N}\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to0.$$ The sequence is clearly exact and the middle term is the direct product of the outer terms (since $2\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb Z$). But the sequence doesn't split on the right: Such a splitting would be injective, hence preserves the order of elements, but no element of $\pi^{-1}(1,0,0,\ldots)$ has order $2$.

The correct link between short exact sequences and semidirect products is the equivalence of the following statements:

The short exact sequence $1\to N\to G\to G/N\to 1$ splits (on the right).
There is an action $\rho$ of $G/N$ on $N$ and an isomorphism $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
1@>>>N @>{}>> G@>>>G/N@>>>1\\
\ @V{\operatorname{id}}VV @V{\Psi}VV@V{\operatorname{id}}VV\ \\
1@>>>N @>{}>> N\rtimes _\rho G/N@>>>G/N@>>>1
\end{CD}
of short exact sequences. (In particular $G\cong N\rtimes_\rho G/N$.)

In other words, the isomorphism $G\cong N\rtimes G/N$ has to be compatible with the short exact sequence.

So we can see that $G\cong N\rtimes G/N$ is strictly weaker than the sequence splitting, and we can see exactly what went wrong in the example: The isomorphism of $2\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb Z$ that we needed to identify the middle term with the product of the outer terms destroys the commutativity of the diagram.
As an aside: One can prove that there is no counterexample for finitely generated abelian groups, i.e. every sequence $0\to A\to A\times B\to B\to 0$ with $A,B$ finitely generated abelian already splits. I'm sure there are plenty of counterexamples for non-abelian groups, but I couldn't think of any right away.

Nice answer. Another relevant post on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80002/do-all-exact-1-to-a-to-a-times-b-to-b-to-1-split-for-finite-groups

The question that remains is whether we can find a counterexample to $1\to N\to G\to G/N\to 1$ splitting when $G\cong N\rtimes G/N$ is finite (note that here the semidirect product is necessarily not a direct product, so $G$ is necessarily non-abelian). Probably there are counterexamples, but I don't know any.

@alexbrandenburgermyerson after looking at the $3$ references in the link, this has to be correct.   Also,  nice that no sleight of hand is necessary.

So long hey thanks my friend
